# Where Does TCP overhead factor in when it comes to Wifi speeds?

Tags: wireless, protocol-theory, bandwidth

Is it taken into account by the standards before they give the theoretical maximums per stream, per generation?

How could the loss in bandwidth due to TCP overhead be calculated?

Comment: Where did you see theoretical per stream maximums?  Also speaking broadly, if you're worried about wifi TCP overhead, I would say this issue is trivial, compared with other wifi bandwidth thieves.

Comment: I was looking at Wikipedia mostly , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11
Under Network PHY standards

Comment: Right I imagine 2.4ghz saturation is a bigger problem when trying to push bandwidth, for example , I suppose I want to know what the breakdown of factors and their affect on wireless standards. I tried to search for it various ways but could not seem to find anything technical.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

802.11 data rates are only reflective of how many "bits per second" are transmitted.  Whether those bits are made up of headers or actual data is not reflected in the data rate.

This is also true of wired speeds.

So, generally speaking in networking, the more efficient the traffic is on the header to data payload ratio, the better off you are.